# Color the edges of a graph in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I would appreciate a piece of advice please : I am aiming to color the edges in a graph, by using IGRAPH package.

It works well for the big graph, however, when I decompose the graph into 2 subgraphs and color code those, the color of the edges change (unexpectedly).

more precisely, as an example -- we have a dataframe :

```
el <- data.frame(Partner1=c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6), Partner2=c(2, 2, 5, 7, 7), TYPE=c("DEL", "DEL", "DUP", "TRA", "TRA"))

el$COLOR[el$TYPE=="DEL"] <- "red"

el$COLOR[el$TYPE=="DUP"] <- "green"

el$COLOR[el$TYPE=="INS"] <- "yellow"

el$COLOR[el$TYPE=="INV"] <- "brown"

el$COLOR[el$TYPE=="TRA"] <- "blue"

g <- graph_from_data_frame(d = el, directed = TRUE)

plot(g, edge.color=el$COLOR)
```

And here decomposing the graph into 2 SUBGRAPHS :

```
g_decompose <- decompose.graph(g)



plot(g_decompose[[1]], edge.color=el$COLOR) ## here the edges are red (that is fine)

plot(g_decompose[[2]], edge.color=el$COLOR) ## here the edges shall be blue and green, not red and green
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using the R code :

```
plot(g_decompose[[1]], edge.color=edge_attr(g_decompose[[1]])$COLOR)
plot(g_decompose[[2]], edge.color=edge_attr(g_decompose[[2]])$COLOR)
```